# knitr::knit not iterating over a list, fails at first chunk

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr

Hopefully someone can help me. At work I've got an RMarkdown document which is intended as a blank template to be filled. In a second R script I have a bunch of code that takes some data, does some processing, then for each group populates the markdown document, saves out the pdf, then repeats for the next group. When I first wrote it two years ago it ran totally fine, but now it fails on the first iteration at the first R chunk and throws an "unexpected input error." Doesn't matter what the R chunk is, it errors out at the first chunk. When I open the Markdown document and manually replace everything and click 'knit' it runs fine.

I think I've got it down to the minimally reproduceable example. Inside of a project I have the markdown file named "TestingForm.Rmd" which is something like...

````
---
title: "Illustrating Problem"
author: "Spudtopia"
date: "3/6/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

This is a test for '&courseTitle'

```{r cars}
print("I'm testing to see if it correctly replaces &courseTitle")
```

## Heading

That's all. That's the test.
````

Then in the R script I have something like...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

things <- c('Thing One','Thing Two','Thing Three')

output_PDFs <- function(various_files) {

  gned_template <- read_file('TestingForm.Rmd')

  gned_template <- str_replace_all(gned_template, c('&courseTitle' = various_files))

  md_filename <- paste0(various_files, "-Test.pdf")

  knitr::knit(text = gned_template, output = md_filename)

}

map(things, ~output_PDFs(.x))
```

You can rearrange the R chunks, the first R chunk always errors out with an "unexpected input" error. I've updated R, I've updated RStudio, and I've updated all my packages. What have I written incorrectly?

Comment: Wouldn´t it be better to use parameters instead of parsing the complete document?

Comment: Does `knitr::knit` actually produce a PDF file?  I thought you used `rmarkdown::render` for that; `knit` just runs the R code and produces an `.md` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `knitr::knit` by `rmarkdown::render` and everything works fine. I added comments where I changed your code. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

things <- c('Thing One','Thing Two','Thing Three')

output_PDFs <- function(various_files) {

  gned_template <- read_file('TestingForm.Rmd')

  gned_template <- str_replace_all(gned_template, '&courseTitle', various_files)

  # Temporary file
  write_file(gned_template, 'TestingForm_tmp.Rmd')

  md_filename <- paste0(various_files, "-Test.pdf")
  # Use rmarkdown::render
  rmarkdown::render(input = 'TestingForm_tmp.Rmd', output_file = md_filename)

}

map(things, ~output_PDFs(.x))
```

Comment: Huh. I guess it was actually that simple. Thanks!